# Correlation between two variables measured in separate experiments in R

Tags: r, regression, correlation, bootstrap, covariance

I'm trying to show a correlation between growth in a petri dish of some fungi and its effect on a plant. I have ten strains of fungi which I tested in the plant and in petri dishes. I can put data from both experiments into linear models (lm) to get estimated means and variances. If I run a regression on the estimated means for each strain I find a significant correlation, but this doesn't take uncertainty in the strain means into account.
So far I've tried a parametric bootstrap, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the ultimate test statistic. I've included the parameter estimates and my R code. At the moment it generates simulated strain means from the estimated parameters. I need a p value for the covariance between growth and virulence. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My specific questions are:
1) Is a parametric boostrap the right way to go about analyzing this?
2) How would one go about doing this in R?

```
Strain  MeanVirulence MeanGrowth    VirulenceVarGrowthVar  
1  -5.26064 0.066716    0.67834 0.053247  
2   -4.05482    -0.055524   0.68385 0.047111  
3   -5.47282    0.029047    0.68385 0.046739  
4   -3.50632    -0.161811   0.68385 0.047083  
5   -4.94051    -0.224949   0.68385 0.04727  
6   -4.04982    -0.062938   0.68385 0.047647  
7   -4.53178    -0.142985   0.68385 0.04788  
8   -3.01697    -0.199349   0.68385 0.047255  
9   -3.81093    -0.254793   0.68385 0.047255  
10  -1.61882    -0.325289   0.68385 0.0469
```

And here is my R code:

```
gendata<-function(par,npar=TRUE,print=TRUE){
    n     = 10
    k     = 2
    x=matrix(data=NA, nrow=n, ncol=k)
    for(i in 1:n){
      x[i,1] = rnorm(1,mean=par[i,2],sd=par[i,4])
      x[i,2] = rnorm(1,mean=par[i,3],sd=par[i,5])
    }
    return(x)
}

lmp <- function (modelobject) {
    f <- summary(modelobject)$fstatistic
    p <- pf(f[1],f[2],f[3],lower.tail=F)
    attributes(p) <- NULL
    return(p)
}


samp=20000
rescor=matrix(data=NA, samp)
resvar=matrix(data=NA, samp)
pvals=matrix(data=NA, samp)
numsig = 0
numnotsig = 0
for (i in 1:samp){
    x<-gendata(parameters)
    rescor[i]<-cor(x[,1],x[,2], method = "pearson")
    resvar[i]<-var(x[,1])
    a<-lm(x[,1]~x[,2])
    pvals[i]<-lmp(a)
    if (pvals[i] < 0.05){
        numsig = numsig + 1
    }
    if (pvals[i] > 0.05){
        numnotsig = numnotsig + 1
    }    
}

Strain Plate Growth  
1      1     200   
1      2     210  
1      3     190  
2      1     150   
2      2     130  
2      3     140  
...  

Strain Plant Growth  
1      1     70  
1      2     40  
1      3     50  
1      4     45  
2      1     80  
2      2     90  
2      3     85  
2      4     75  
...
```

Comment: So, for each of 10 fungi don't you just have two variables - effect on plant and growth in dish?  Why can't you just correlate those? Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't have actual measurements for each variable, just estimates from my samples. I can run a correlation on the strain means, but I should take the variances within the strain measurements into account.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by not having measurements, just estimates from a sample. Can you show some of your data?

Comment: Sure, I've added an example of what the data looks like. For "growth" I have measurements from 16 plates per strain. For "virulence" I have measurement from 13 plants per strain. So I want to correlate strain growth and strain virulence but I need to take the within strain variance for both variables into account.